# UIImageView UITapGestureRecognizer not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

Tap gesture event not gettint called. I may be doing something wrong, but please have a look (I tried adding recognizer to self.view but still no luck) :

**LoginViewController**

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let container = UIView() 

        container.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true

        let myVC1 = MyViewController()
        let myVC2 = MyViewController()
        let myVC3 = MyViewController()
        let myVC4 = MyViewController()

        let myStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [myVC1.view, myVC2.view, myVC3.view, myVC4.view])
        myStackView.spacing = 10
        myStackView.alignment = .Fill
        myStackView.distribution = .EqualSpacing

        container.addSubview(myStackView)
        view.addSubview(container)
    }
}
```

**MyViewController**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    let ImageView = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pressedSocialMediaItem(_:)))
        tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        ImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        ImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        view.addSubview(ImageView)
    }

    func pressedSocialMediaItem(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) { 
        print("PRESSED ! ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer. But also you need to initialise your imageView which I can't see in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, so I got it working somehow. All I need to do was to add view controllers inside my LoginViewController like so:

```
self.addChildViewController(myVC1)
```

Instead of using `view.addSubview(container)`

Notice: I'm not sure it is the correct way of doing this, and please comment if it's not. Meanwhile it solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `MyViewController.pressedSocialMediaItem`, so your code should work like this.

```
 class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

        let ImageView = UIImageView()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            ImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.pressedSocialMediaItem(_:)))
            tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
            tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

            ImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            ImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

            view.addSubview(ImageView)
        }

        func pressedSocialMediaItem(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) { 
            print("PRESSED ! ")
        }
    }
```

I have tested the following on my machine and it works:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.pressedSocialMediaItem(_:)))
        tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    func pressedSocialMediaItem(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("PRESSED ! ")
    }


}
```

Comment: I tried adding MyViewController.pressedSocialMediaItem but still not working. What do you mean I need to initialize my imageView. Isn't it initialized from my let statement?